# Access Sharepoint Online Wiki without login

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages

We have created a Wiki page in Sharepoint Online. Is it possible to share this externally and allow users access without login in? 
Or can I embed this within another ASP.Net site to enable them to view content from my web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable exteranal sharing in SharePoint Online.

Please go to SharePoint Online admin center-> policies-> Sharing. Set the level to "Anyone."
[image]

Thus you could share the wiki page to anyone with the link.

[image]

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off

Comment: Thanks for the link @Michael. Though this has been enabled, it didn't work. 

I had to go to the Sites > Active Sites >  and enable External Sharing with Anyone.

Assume this is additional protection settings at site level.

Comment: I made the settings to Anyone - User can share that don't require sign in.
However, when shared, its prompts following :
To view the information on this page, you need to verify your identity.Click to provide additional credentials.

Answer (score 1):

No, anonymous access is not possible. Earlier there was a special public site collection for this purpose, but it was discontinued in 2015.

As to the second part of your question, I do not think embedding it would be ok even if you managed to solve the authentication bit somehow. I would consider making a public wiki on another service or look into external sharing with authenticated users as Michael Han mentioned in another answer.